# iPhone - Uploading an app prefs file to the iPhone

Tags: iphone, file-upload, version, preferences

I'm working on a new preference file and I'm testing the app on the iPhone (I must do on th e iPhone because I work on a camera project).

During my test, I have to change my code to make sure the new preference file is well writen. As I have many tries to do this, how may I upload to the iPhone a 1.0 preference file I've downloaded earlier from the 1.0 app, to be able to test again with a new compiled 1.0.1 app ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable iTunes file sharing(set UIFileSharingEnabled to YES in your app's Info.plist) and then read your file from the Documents folder. This way you'll be able to access it semi-directly via iTunes.

Don't forget to move it someplace else when finished debugging, unless you want your users to see that file, too.

Comment: What if I don't have anymore the project that have been used to create the app ?

Comment: you'll still need to modify the actual app to read the uploaded file - so you do have to be able to recompile it.